# What's the English title of "금수회의록" by 안국선?

Tags: translation

Anyonw know whether there is an English translation of 금수회의록 online or in print?  If so, what is the English title?  (Author is [안국선](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%95%88%EA%B5%AD%EC%84%A0))

I don't find it in Google books, but I do find a few online editions of the Korean.  Also not in worldcat (except the original) nor in Amazon nor in bookfinder.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why all the comments are gone, but maybe we should revert the question title because it seems OP was asking for the translation of the novel itself?

Comment: @jick I do understand that the asker wants to find an English translation of the novel - but while "what is the English translation of this book's title" seems a fair enough question for this site, I would think that "is there an English translation of this book" possibly crosses the line to not really being a question about the Korean language. I know that sounds like splitting hairs, but hopefully by answering the question as worded we'd provide the necessary info anyway.

Comment: If an adequate English translation of the book exists, the title would help me find it.  (Which would help my language study.)  However, the title of a translation is not guaranteed to be a translation of the title.  The full text of the original is online, but cleaning up the output of Google translate is not a welcome task.

Comment: While I don't know of an English translation, the title 금수회의록 is rendered in Hanja as 禽獸會議錄, and if you're looking for a rough translation of this it means `Records/diaries (록, 錄) of [a/the] meeting/s (회의, 會議) of/between [the] birds and beasts (금수, 禽獸).`. *Birds and beasts* is a synonym of *bestial* or *inhuman*, if that helps.

Comment: If you Google that translation, you'll get various references by authors who have translated it as: `Record of the Conference of Birds and Beasts`, `Notes from the Meeting of the Birds and Beasts`, though I don't see any clues of an English translation of the entire text.

Comment: If you had not included the followup comment, I would have said it doesn't help because "the title of a translation is not guaranteed to be a translation of the title."  But your followup gives me some hope that some variation of those might pay off.  캄사합니다!

Comment: I don’t think there is an actual translation for that. You can simply say Geum-su-Hue-I-Lok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [*Understanding Korean Literature* by Hung-Gyu Kim, Robert Fouser](https://books.google.com/books?id=x4QYDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT235&dq=%E7%A6%BD%E7%8D%B8%E6%9C%83%E8%AD%B0%E9%8C%84&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSndiXndDbAhWSPH0KHXwRDVQQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%E7%A6%BD%E7%8D%B8%E6%9C%83%E8%AD%B0%E9%8C%84&f=false), it means "Minutes From a Meeting of Animals". Unfortunately, I cannot find a translated version of the book.

The Korean version is [금수회의록](https://ko.wikisource.org/wiki/%EA%B8%88%EC%88%98%ED%9A%8C%EC%9D%98%EB%A1%9D).

And while I was searching I found a news article about this novel: [“신소설 대표작 ‘금수회의록’은 日소설 번안 작품”](http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_news/khan_art_view.html?artid=201102240327485).
It is an adapted story, the original story or book is from Japan.